# Qt C++ Help Showing a Moving Image using PixMap

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I'm using Qt in c++ to code plants z zombies which involves me moving things across the screen.
To do that, I'm using QTimer which I've connected to the advance() function.

I'm able to get my object to move (using qDebug and seeing the coordinates) but I don't physically see the picture change unless I refresh the screen or switch windows (e.g. pressing alt tab twice or clicking the windows key button)

This is an example of one of my classes. Here I'm trying to get my peas move across the screen.

```
#ifndef BULLETS_H
#define BULLETS_H

#include <QPoint>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QRectF>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QVector>
#include <QImage>
#include <QWidget>
//#include "mainwindow.h"


class bullets : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    QRectF boundingRect() const {return QRectF(this->x,0, 20,20);}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

    bullets(int xPlant, int yPlant, QImage bullet);
    ~bullets() {}

    void advance(int phase); //Moves the bullet across the screen

    int x;
    int y;

    QGraphicsPixmapItem *bulletsPixMap;
    QImage pea_picture;

    int velocity;
};

#endif
```

along with the corresponding cpp file

```
#include "bullets.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>

int counter = 0;

bullets::bullets(int xPlant, int yPlant,QImage bullet)
{
    velocity = 10;
    x = xPlant;
    y = yPlant;
    pea_picture = bullet;
}

void bullets::advance(int phase)
{
    if (!phase)
        return;
    x += (velocity * 0.5);
    //  setPos(x,y);
}

void bullets::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->drawPixmap(this->x,this->y,QPixmap::fromImage(pea_picture));

    /*
    QBrush b(QColor(0,252,0));
    painter->setBrush(b);
    painter->drawEllipse(boundingRect());
    */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the `update()` function?

Comment: Nope! Where should I call that from?

Comment: Since you already have the timer connected to `advance`, perhaps that would be a good choice.

Comment: I called it in my advance function and it didn't make a difference, any other places to call it from?